# ANDROID: SQLite - ListView 2 Lines

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I wanted to start working and understanding SQlite, so that's why I started to try to understand and programm the Notepad-Tutorial at the android developer page. But in the ListView they only display the title of the Note you create but not the body. So I want to show the title and the body in a ListView-item. Here is my code:

The NoteActivity Class:

```
public class NoteActivity extends ListActivity
{
    private  static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    private static final int ACTIVITY_CREATE=0;
    private static final int ACTIVITY_EDIT=1;
    private static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;


    Context ctx;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ctx = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.notepad_list);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        fillData();

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    private void fillData() {

        Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();

        // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
        notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(notesCursor);



         //This code works only to display the title in the ListView:
        /*
        // Create an array to specify the fields we want to display in the list (only TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE};

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind those fields to (in this case just text1)
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.text1};

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, notesCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
        */


        //Here I want to use a SimpleAdapter to display the title and body of the Note
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter
                (this, list, R.layout.custom_row_view, new String[] {"title","body"}, new int[] {R.id.text11,R.id.text2});


        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("title",NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
        temp.put("body", NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY);
        list.add(temp);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID,0, R.string.menu_insert);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case INSERT_ID:
                createNote();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                    ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.add(0,DELETE_ID,0,R.string.menu_delete);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case DELETE_ID:
                AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
                mDbHelper.deleteNote(info.id);
                fillData();
                Toast.makeText(this,"Note deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createNote() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CREATE);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NoteEdit.class);
        i.putExtra(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, id);
        startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        fillData();

    }
```

I used the menu buttons to create the notes but you can ignore them, the importat method is "fillData()". I don't understand that why the ListView displays the two strings "titl" and "body" and not the content of the title and body.

And here is my NoteEdit class which I use to create/edit the notes:

```
public class NoteEdit extends Activity {

    private EditText mTitleText;
    private EditText mBodyText;
    private Button confirmButton;
    private Long mRowId;
    private NotesDbAdapter mDbHelper;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new NotesDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.note_edit);
        setTitle(R.string.edit_note);

        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mBodyText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.body);
        confirmButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);

        mRowId = (savedInstanceState == null) ? null :
                (Long) savedInstanceState.getSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);
        if (mRowId == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            mRowId = extras != null ? extras.getLong(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID)
                    : null;
        }

        populateFields();

    }

    public void confirmButton(View view)
    {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.confirm:

                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
        }
    }

    @Deprecated
    private void populateFields() {
        if (mRowId != null) {
            Cursor note = mDbHelper.fetchNote(mRowId);
            startManagingCursor(note);
            mTitleText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE)));
            mBodyText.setText(note.getString(
                    note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY)));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        saveState();
        outState.putSerializable(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        saveState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        populateFields();
    }

    private void saveState() {
        String title = mTitleText.getText().toString();
        String body = mBodyText.getText().toString();

        if (mRowId == null) {
            long id = mDbHelper.createNote(title, body);
            if (id > 0) {
                mRowId = id;
            }
        } else {
            mDbHelper.updateNote(mRowId, title, body);
        }
    }
}
```

And here my NotesDBAdapter class:

/**
 * Simple notes database access helper class. Defines the basic CRUD operations
 * for the notepad example, and gives the ability to list all notes as well as
 * retrieve or modify a specific note.

*/
public class NotesDbAdapter {

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;


public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "body";
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";

private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";

private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;


private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "title text not null, body text not null);";


private final Context mCtx;


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 *
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work

 */
public NotesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 *
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws android.database.SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public NotesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

/**
 * Create a new note using the title and body provided. If the note is
 * successfully created return the new rowId for that note, otherwise return
 * a -1 to indicate failure.
 *
 * @param title the title of the note
 * @param body the body of the note

 */
public long createNote(String title, String body) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    initialValues.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

/**
 * Delete the note with the given rowId
 * @param rowId id of note to delete
 * @return true if deleted, false otherwise
 */
public boolean deleteNote(long rowId) {

    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor over the list of all notes in the database
 *
 * @return Cursor over all notes
 */
public Cursor fetchAllNotes() {

    return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_BODY}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

/**
 * Return a Cursor positioned at the note that matches the given rowId
 * @param rowId id of note to retrieve
 * @return Cursor positioned to matching note, if found
 * @throws android.database.SQLException if note could not be found/retrieved
 */
public Cursor fetchNote(long rowId) throws SQLException {

    Cursor mCursor =

        mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_TITLE, KEY_BODY}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;

}

/**
 * Update the note using the details provided. The note to be updated is
 * specified using the rowId, and it is altered to use the title and body
 * values passed in
 *
 * @param rowId id of note to update
 * @param title value to set note title to
 * @param body value to set note body to
 * @return true if the note was successfully updated, false otherwise
 */
public boolean updateNote(long rowId, String title, String body) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
    args.put(KEY_BODY, body);

    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

}

I did not post the  xml-files because I thinks don't you need them, the main problem is the "fillData" method, I don't know how to post 2 lines from the database in a listView

I also tried some other tutorials but I couldn't managed to get it work

Comment: I'd suggest pasting the code here rather than a link to it. Make sure you use the "block code" style.

Comment: yeah but I think it would be too long and hard to read, I thought if I just post the links it would be more clear instead of scrolling the whole time

Comment: I understand, but it's best to paste it here: the link you post in the future might no longer be accessible, and this might interest other people too. Also, in some countries that site might be blocked (mine for example) and I can't view the code in order to help you.

Comment: Yeah you are right Joy, sorry

Comment: Are `NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE` and `NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY` meant to be column names from your database?

Comment: @marcus.ramsden yeah, I edited my post and now you can see my DataBase access helper class(NotesDbAdapter), now it should be clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `fillData()` method from what I can tell. You are passing in the column names as the values rather than the actual values from the cursor.

```
HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
temp.put("title",NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
temp.put("body", NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY);
list.add(temp);
```

This seems to be incorrect. Instead you should be doing something along the following lines;

```
private void fillData() {
    // Get all of the rows from the database and create the item list
    Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
    startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

    // The list that will back our table, this could be turned into a member variable.
    List<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    // Get the column indexes
    int titleColumnIndex = notesCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE);
    int bodyColumnIndex = notesCursor.getColumnIndex(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_BODY);

    // Iterate through all of the cursor rows to fill the adapter
    while (notesCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String title = notesCursor.getString(titleColumnIndex);
        String body = notesCursor.getString(bodyColumnIndex);

        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("title", title);
        temp.put("body", body);
        list.add(temp);
    }

    //Here I want to use a SimpleAdapter to display the title and body of the Note
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter
            (this, list, R.layout.custom_row_view, new String[] {"title","body"}, new int[] {R.id.text11,R.id.text2});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

For more about the [`Cursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) as you will be making pretty extensive use of it when working with databases in Android.

Also for a possibly clearer answer with regards to working with cursors check out [section 4](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#databasetutorial) of this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: Yep that should replace where you build the HashMap originally in the fillData() method.

Comment: so you mean to use the cursors which I used to get the rows form the database?:  

Cursor notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
notesCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllNotes();
startManagingCursor(notesCursor);

Comment: sry I am new..dont know how to format the code in these small comments

Comment: I've added a little more context to my answer.

Comment: yeah sry to bother you again but the problem is now that If I use  String title = notesCursor.getString(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE); the IDE marks it as an error, because getString expects an int as a parameter, the exact errorsays: getString(int) cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)

Comment: Sorry typing too quickly. Cursor getString methods take a column index. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Yeah it works, I can add new notes, thank you very much, now I can add notes but cannot edit/delete them I get a CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException but now that's my concern^^, thanks again very much